# VUEJS -> ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, deployment, digital-ocean, webpack-5

Im using Vuejs 2 with webpack 5 and getting this problem:

```
 ERROR  ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
         - options has an unknown property 'public'. These properties are valid:
           object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'public'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
    at validate (C:\Users\erbisilva\Documents\GitHub\hefesto\hefesto-website\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158:11)
    at new Server (C:\Users\erbisilva\Documents\GitHub\hefesto\hefesto-website\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:270:5)
    at serve (C:\Users\erbisilva\Documents\GitHub\hefesto\hefesto-website\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:194:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I found a lot of other posts, nothing helped me:

```
put allowedhosts to all
deleted node_modules and .lock.json
changed package.json file
```

Still same problem

With version 4.5 (I believe) it works with:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
      public: process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN,
      port: 8000
  },
})
```

But with webpack 5 it seems to be a problem and I cant solve it

Could someone give me some "light"? I'm trying to deploy my project to digitalocean.
If I deploy without the devServer it gives me an error:

```
Invalid host header
```

I think its because I'm missing the devServer configuration. But when I add it, I have that problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: `public` was removed in favor of `client.webSocketURL`. Check this migration guide: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md

Comment: @PrerakSola thanks for the link. That means I need to replace my code to something like: module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    sockHost: process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN,
    sockPort: 8080,
  },
}; right?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 4.5:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
      public: process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN,
      port: 8000
  },
})
```

change to:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    client: {
      // Can be `string`:
      //
      // To get protocol/hostname/port from browser
      // webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'
      webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After the change:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  lintOnSave: false,
  devServer: {
    client: {
      // Can be `string`:
      //
      // To get protocol/hostname/port from browser
      // webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'
      webSocketURL: {
        hostname: process.env.VUE_APP_DOMAIN,
        pathname: "/ws",
        port: 8000,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I'm getting this error when I try to access the page. Im using Digital Ocean to deploy

```
ERROR
Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
    at new WebSocketClient (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/clients/WebSocketClient.js:18:19)
    at initSocket (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js:34:12)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app&port=8000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true:332:55)
    at ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app&port=8000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&progress=true&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true (https://coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app/js/chunk-vendors.js:2530:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (https://coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app/js/app.js:1417:33)
    at https://coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app/js/app.js:2537:83
    at __webpack_require__.O (https://coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app/js/app.js:1463:23)
    at https://coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app/js/app.js:2540:53
    at https://coral-app-qeatm.ondigitalocean.app/js/app.js:2542:12
```